# C# filter JS files from HttpWebRequest/WebResponse

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, split

I searched but could not find anything that worked for me.

A while ago I started with C# and my first personal project was a simple WebCrawler.
It should check the sourcecode for special Strings to identify if for example Google Analytics or something similar is included.

So it works fine but of course I'm missing the JS and Iframes since HttpWebRequest does not render the website as I know.

So I wanted to check for `"<script src=""` for example and then get the URL through a split.
But this does not work as expected and I don't think this is a clean and good way.

Since I'm checking for strings it could be destroyed by simply changing the string from `"<script"` to `"< script"` as example so I have no idea how to get a specific string from a big string.

I found regular expressions (rex) and split but I'm not sure if rex and split would be good since there could be more types of `"src="` or `split("\"", "\"", text)`

I don't want a "here you go" of course I want to understand and to do it myself but I have no idea where to go from here..

Sorry for the long text and no examples but at the moment I have no access and there is not really much except for rex and split's

EDIT: I think I'll create a class which checks every char for a special row like "

Best,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Html agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

I haven't used it personally, but something like this should work (i haven't tested it):

```
string url = "some/url";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);  

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(streamReader.ReadToEnd());

var scripts = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                             .Where(n => n.Name == "script");
```

this should get you all script nodes to do with them what you want =)

Comment: this looks better than my class till now :D
I started to creat a class that checks every char and if it is in a special row, if so every char should be written in an string till the next char is an '"' but I think this is not clean and good.

I'll try this it looks really problemsolving :)

Comment: glad i could help, or at least point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

So I found a way to get the JS URL here is my code

```
List<string> srcurl = new List<string>();
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("some/url");
HtmlNodeCollection linkNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script[@src]");

foreach (HtmlNode linkNode in linkNodes)
   {
      HtmlAttribute link = linkNode.Attributes["src"];
      srcurl.Add(link.Value);
   }
```

Regarding the code from @avidenic, if you want to use it be aware to use

```
doc.LoadHtml(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
```

Best,
Mike